Binding of M Query parameter is not working in Power BI
I have created a power BI report in Direct query mode against a Data bricks SQL warehouse source. I need to make use of M query parameters for optimal data rendering and was hoping to bind the parameter value, to be used in the SQL query, from a field used in the slicer. The default value that is provided manually is getting applied in the filter of the query properly but the slicer value selected is not getting bound. The datatypes of the field and the parameter are same. Source table is connected in direct query. I have been trying to identify what is it that I am missing and any suggestion to resolve this would be of great help!
I tried all the steps detailed in the documentation. I was expecting the parameter binding to work dynamically.
